# Solve $2^x + 3^{2x + 2} = 5$

Tags: exponential-function, roots

Out of curiosity, how would you approach the following exponential equation:
$$2^x + 3^{2x + 2} = 5$$

This resulted from a work on a system of logarithmic equations and I know for a fact that it has a single solution, $x \approx -0.345464$, which I obtained with the help of Wolfram Alpha. Anyhow, I simply can't figure out a way to solve for $x$ in an enclosed form.

My main question would be: is the solution generally expressable as a real number in a closed form? Or is this equation a dead end and maybe I should reconsider my approach to the system of equations?

That also brought me to the following thought. The equation can be rewritten as:
$$2^x + 9\cdot 9^x - 5 = 0$$
which is a general composition of exponential functions. I couldn't find any general approaches to such general exponential equations, but my intuition is that there's not much 'general' stuff to do with them and all depends on the current case.

I hope you could understand me, my terminology is perhaps not very precise and I'm a bit self learned in mathematics, so any clarification is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally speaking, equations of this type don't have simple, closed form solutions.  Numerical methods, of the sort employed by Wolfram Alpha, are called for.

Comment: If you're lucky, there is a simple (usually integer, usually close to $0$) solution to these equations. If you're not lucky, there isn't really much you can do.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, that's what I also thought after struggling for a while.. I'm starting to consider a typo in the problem from the book itself, because when one instance of one varaible is removed, everything fits perfectly together. But I thought that was simply a somewhat more interesting problem. I will edit the original post with my thoughts on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one can solve this "nicely". However, the following graph may help! Even if you can't solve it *by hand*, you can always get an idea of what range of values should the solution fall within.

If you really want to solve it numerically, the **Newton-Raphson** method is just one of the many methods you could try out to obtain the root of $f(x) = 2^x + 3^{2x+2} - 5$. Note that $f'(x)>0$ so there's *only **one** solution*.

[image]

Comment: I played a lot with the graph, before posting this question. My main goal was to just figure out whether I'm missing something or there's simply no "nice" solution, as you described it, which was my intuition as well. Thank you for the answer, I'm starting to convince myself that there was a typo in the initial system of equations!

Comment: No problem! I would encourage you to also look at **numerical methods** such as Newton-Raphson to attack these equations if you really want to solve them.

Comment: Also, in my experience, more often than not we've to just **guess** one or two solutions by inspection and show that more solutions do not exist (using derivatives, maybe). Of course, this wasn't possible in this case, but if you find something like $2^x + 3^x = 2$, this idea will come in handy.

Comment: As two quick examples, $2^x + 3^{2x + 2} = 10$ or $2^{x+1} + 3^{2x + 1} = 5$ would have been *nicer problems* to solve, and you could get away with the derivative "trick".

Comment: This is a homework problem from a book, so it really should not be about figuring out approximations for an unclosed solution, but rather exercising some logarithmic and exponential regularities and properties. I know about numerical methods, I've read a couple of sources on numerology, which I see as a really powerful practical savior for such situations. So it really is useful! But the purpose here should be different. Anyways, thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

As you expect, you cannot get a closed form solution.

Consider that ou are looking for the zero of function
$$f(x)=2^x + 3^{2x + 2}-5$$ By inspection, you know that the solution is somewhere between $-1$ and $0$.

Try Taylor expansion
$$f(x)=5+x (\log (2)+18 \log (3))+x^2 \left(\frac{\log ^2(2)}{2}+18 \log ^2(3)\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$$
Using the first term only, you have, as an *estimate*
$$x=-\frac{5}{\log (2)+18 \log (3)}\approx -0.244282$$ Now, use more terms and use series reversion to get
$$x=t-\frac{ \left(\log ^2(2)+36 \log ^2(3)\right)}{2 (\log (2)+18 \log (3))}t^2 +O\left(t^3\right)\quad \text{with} \quad t=\frac{f(x)-5}{\log (2)+18 \log (3)}$$ Making $f(x)=0$ as we desire, then another estimate
$$x=-\frac{5 \left(7 \log ^2(2)+828 \log ^2(3)+72 \log (2) \log (3)\right)}{2 (\log   (2)+18 \log (3))^3}\approx -0.30832$$

Now, let us polish the root using the so simple Newton method and, since I am lazy, I shall start with the first estimate I wrote. The successive iterates are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & -0.2442817505 \\
 1 & -0.3353427850 \\
 2 & -0.3453567313 \\
 3 & -0.3454642504 \\
 4 & -0.3454642627
\end{array}
\right)$$ and we could get as many decimal figures as required. For the fun of it, the solution
$$-0.345464262655186305826853008027166943006071510\cdots$$